# D3 Pack text weird behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bootstrap-modal

I am experiencing weird behaviors coming from D3's Pack layout. As seen in the two pictures below sometimes the text is not placed properly. In the good picture is an application I have developed already. In the picture with the bug is the same application that I am trying to put into a bootstrap modal dialog. I am using the same code and it should work but for some reason it is not. I am still looking into it but was wondering if anyone had a clue on what is going on.

```
    var node = svg.select("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(root.descendants())
        .enter().append("g")
        .style("opacity", function(d){return  1/(Math.max(1,d.height))})
        .attr("r", function(d){return d.r})
          .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," +d.y+ ")"; })
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (!d.children ? " node--leaf" : d.depth ? "" : " node--root"); })
           .each(function(d) { d.node = this; })
           .attr("value", function(d){return d.value})
           .on("mouseover", hoveredPack(true))
           .on("mouseout", hoveredPack(false))
           .on("dblclick", function(d){transform = zoomByDoubleClick(d, width, transform, root, node)} )


var leaf = node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

var colors = generateColors(leaf, data);

var circle = node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r})
    //.attr("padding", function(d){return 20})

    .style("fill", function(d){
        return colors[d.id];
    });

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(function(d,i){return d.r;})
    .outerRadius(function(d,i){return d.r;})
    .startAngle(Math.PI)
    .endAngle(3*Math.PI);

node.append("path")
    .attr("fill","red")
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "s"+i;})
    .attr("d",arc);

node.append("text")
.text(function(d){ return (d.r>50)? d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf("@") + 1) : "";})

    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#s"+i;})
    .attr("startOffset",function(d,i){return "25%";})
    .style("opacity", function(d){ return 1/Math.log(Math.max(1,d.height))})
```

[image: Good Capture]

[image: Weird Capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem is somehow related to Bootstrap's modal dialog. I tried coping the element in a blank div on a blank page and it worked fine.

So I am no longer adding my d3 to a modal dialog. I am just working around the problem.